# How do I change the compiler in Xcode

Tags: c, xcode, gcc, xcode4

I'm compiling a C code in Xcode 4.6.3, however I don't know which compiler I'm using. I need to use gcc 4.2.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to use GCC?

Comment: It's an exercise and my professor said to use gcc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you *really* need to change to gcc, you can do so in the build settings:

[image]

[image]